# Is there a way using SVNKit to get the names of the changed methods rather than the whole contents?

Tags: svn, diff, svnkit

I am using SVNKit to be able to use my Subversion. Now according to [here](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#terse-diff) Subversion does allow the retrieval of the names of the methods which have been changed. 
Now in SVNKit, I am currently using doDiff to get the differences in file contents. However I need just a list of the methods being modified and the number of lines which have been modified... Is there a way to be able to do so using SVNKIt?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

By default, the output of `svn diff` is in the [unified diff format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Unified_format).
You need to parse it to get the changes you need to highlight in the file between the different revisions.

Also, SVNKit let you specify a diff driver when using the `SVNDiffClient` class, using the [setDiffGenerator()](http://svnkit.com/kb/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/wc/SVNDiffClient.html#setDiffGenerator%28org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.ISVNDiffGenerator%29) method.
You can write a class that implements [ISVNDiffGenerator](http://svnkit.com/kb/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/wc/ISVNDiffGenerator.html) to have the diff outputted in the format you need.